# How to add voters to the default AccessDecisionManager?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I'd like to add some business logic to my spring application's authorization process and I think that implement a custom AccessDecisionVoter is the best solution.

That would be great, but I haven't found any way to add this new voter to the authorization process without completely redefine the AccessDecisionManager bean. This is very inconvenient because my business logic should be added transparently and does not require any specific decision manager. Instead, it should only tells his opinion (vote) and let the enclosing application apply its own authorization policy.

Even the spring security's suggested example (https://spring.io/blog/2009/01/03/spring-security-customization-part-2-adjusting-secured-session-in-real-time) uses this approach.

I have found also a promissing solution at http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/security/109476-how-to-add-voters-to-the-default-accessdecisionmanager?p=570570#post570570, that might add additional voters to any AbstractAccessDecisionManager using a bean post processor, but the method setDecisionVoters (key to such solution) is deprecated and thus it's out of question.

So, I was wondering if there is some way to add my voter to the current AccessDecisionManager without having to take care of it. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

```
@Component
public class AccessDecisionManagerCustomizer {

    @Autowired protected MethodInterceptor methodSecurityInterceptor;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {

        if (methodSecurityInterceptor instanceof MethodSecurityInterceptor) {

            AccessDecisionManager accessDecisionManager = ((MethodSecurityInterceptor) methodSecurityInterceptor).getAccessDecisionManager();
            if (accessDecisionManager instanceof AbstractAccessDecisionManager) {

                List<AccessDecisionVoter<? extends Object>> voters = ((AbstractAccessDecisionManager) accessDecisionManager).getDecisionVoters();
                // do something with voters

            } else

                throw new IllegalStateException(String.format("Access decision manager is of: %s, can't register custom voter",
                    accessDecisionManager.getClass().getSimpleName()));

        } else

            throw new IllegalStateException(String.format("Method security interceptor is of: %s, can't register custom voter",
                methodSecurityInterceptor.getClass().getSimpleName()));

    }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

AfirmativeBean Extends AbstractAccessDecisionManager. Just use getDecisionVoters() and add one to the list

```
AfirmativeBean  afirmativeBean = (AfirmativeBean)bean);
afirmativeBean.getDecisionVoters().add(yourvoter);
```